# magento 2.3.0 Product With customizable options showing error The product's required option(s) weren't entered

Tags: error, magento2.3.0, customizable-options

On Magento 2.3.0 i created simple product
Then i added 1 customizable option with checkbox not required.
After saving product when i click on Add to cart button without selecting checkbox (Because it is not required field) it shows me this error

The product's required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the options are entered and try again.

[image]

I searched for this error and i found that someone raised this issue before on github

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19267

Definitely this is critical bug on magento 2.3.0 version and still not fixed by them. 
We updated our store from 2.2 to 2.3 on dev server for testing.After facing this error it seems like its not good solution to update to magento 2.3 version.  Can anyone provide me quick fix of this error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a fix submitted for 2.3.1, but you could manually apply it to 2.3.0.

Depending on how you installed Magento, the path could also be

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/19272/files/55d1e26d2e174d7e10823821bbdaa7c081fceae5

Comment: The github link does not work.

Comment: Here is the updated link. However now that 2.3.1 has been released it would be recommended to upgrade instead of using this fix. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/19272/files

Comment: @JoeyCarder,this issue still there on 2.3.4, after changing this file also, I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The link to the fix is : https://github.com/ErikPel/magento2/blob/4f1848a2351ebdd1857fb9881be2cc8d2f63c7b1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php][1].

Apologies I can't comment yet as repulation is less than 50.
Anyways just create a directory structure as YourMagentoDirectory/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/ and paste the above Select.php file to override the 2.3.0 version file.

Comment: thanks but its better to upgrade to magento 2.3.1